# Como colocar el titulo del grafico al momento de exportar a pdf highchart?

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf, highcharts

No me coloca el titulo en grafico en el PDF, porque hice una función afuera del script del  highchart para que me tomara los títulos dinámicamente, ya que cuando lo trate de poner dentro de la función highchart no me actualizaba el nombre del título. Ahora quisiera saber como poner llamar al titulo para que al momento de exportar el PDF aparezca el título
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Adjuntare el codigo

FiltroGrafico.php

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0-rc.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-3-typeahead/4.0.2/bootstrap3-typeahead.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function datostitulo(){
         var autocomplete = document.getElementById("autocomplete").value;
         var cod_curso = document.getElementById("cod_curso").value;
         var seccion = document.getElementById("seccion").value;
         var anio = document.getElementById("anio").value;

         var semestre = document.getElementById("semestre").value;
         var data = '&autocomplete='+autocomplete+'&cod_curso='+cod_curso+'&seccion='+seccion+'&anio='+anio+'&semestre='+semestre;
             $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'datos.php',
                data: data,
                beforeSend: function() {
                console.log(data);

                },
                success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                   $('#titulo').html(data);

                }
            })
            return false;
            };





        </script>
       
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container-fluid" style="margin-left: 30px;">
           <div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
              <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" href="../../principalN.php">Volver</a>
               </div>
               <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-2">
                   <input class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" type="button" onclick="printDiv('areaImprimir')" value="Imprimir" />
            <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" id="button3">Excel</button>
            <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" id="button4">PDF</button>
            <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" id="button5">PNG</button>
            <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" id="button6">JPG</button>
               </div>
               <br>
               <br>
                
            <form id="formulario" class="form-inline" method="post" style="margin-left: 5%; margin-top: 2%;">

                <div class="form-group">

                <label >Seleccione Asignatura:</label>
                <input class="form-control" name="cursos" id="autocomplete">
               </div>


           <div class="form-group" >
            <input class="form-control" id="cod_curso" name="cod_curso" style="display:none;">
           </div>


           <div id="secciones" class="form-group"></div>


            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="sel1">Seleccione año:</label>
                <select class="form-control" name="anio" id="anio" placeholder="" required>
                  <option value=2015>2015
                  <option value=2016>2016
                  <option value=2017>2017
                  <option value=2018>2018
                  <option value=2019>2019
               </select>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="sel1">Seleccione semestre:</label>
                <select class="form-control" name="semestre" id="semestre" placeholder="" required>
                  <option value=Primer>Primer
                  <option value=Segundo>Segundo
               </select>
            </div>

                <div class="form-group">
            

                    <button  id="myButton" type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="datostitulo();grafico();">Generar</button>
                        
                    
                </div>


            </form>
            </div>
        </div>
<br>

 
        <div class="container-fluid" style="margin-left: 30px;margin-top: 10px">
          
        
    
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12" id="areaImprimir">
               <center><div id='titulo'></div></center>
                <div id="grafico" style="width: 1250px; height: 550px;">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
       
       
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-3-typeahead/4.0.2/bootstrap3-typeahead.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0-rc.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>


        <script>

function grafico(){

          $.ajax({
              url: "grafico.php",
              data: $("#formulario").serialize(),
              type: "POST",
              dataType: "json",
              success: function(data) {
                  console.log(data);
                  Highcharts.chart('grafico', {
                      chart: {
                          type: 'column'
                      },
                      title: {
                          text: null
                      },
                      navigation: {
buttonOptions: {
  enabled: false
  }
 },

                      xAxis: {
                          min: 0,
                          title: {
                              text: ''
                          }
                      },
                      xAxis: {
                          categories:   [
                              <?php
                          $sql = "SELECT * FROM preguntas";
                          $result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql);
                          while ($registros = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                          {
                              ?>

                                  '<?php echo $registros["id_pregunta"].".- ".$registros["nombre"] ?>',
                              <?php
                          }
                          ?>
                              ]

                      },
                      yAxis: {
                          min: 0,
                          title: {
                              text: 'Porcentajes'
                          }
                      },
                      tooltip: {
                          pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}</span>: <b>{point.y}</b> ({point.percentage:.0f}%)<br/>',
                          shared: true
                      },
                      plotOptions: {
                          column: {
                              stacking: 'percent'
                          }

                      },
                      series: [{
                         name: 'No aplica',
                          data:  deDataAUnArreglo(data.consulta1.cantidad_respuestas)
                      }, {
                          name: 'Muy en desacuerdo',
                          data: deDataAUnArreglo(data.consulta2.cantidad_respuestas)
                      }, {
                          name: 'En desacuerdo',
                          data:  deDataAUnArreglo(data.consulta3.cantidad_respuestas)
                      }, {
                          name: 'En acuerdo',
                          data:  deDataAUnArreglo(data.consulta4.cantidad_respuestas)
                      }, {
                          name: 'Muy de acuerdo',
                          data:  deDataAUnArreglo(data.consulta5.cantidad_respuestas)
                      }]
                  });
              },
              error: function(xhr) {console.log(xhr.responseText);},
          }).fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ){
              if (jqXHR.status === 0){
                  alert('No hay coneccion con el servidor, debe comunicarte con el administrador');
              } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
                  alert('La pagina solicitada no fue encontrada: error 404, debes comunicarte con el administrador');
              } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                  alert('Error interno del servidor, debes comunicarte con el administrador');
              } else if (textStatus === 'parsererror') {
                  alert('Error en la respuesta JSON, debes comunicarte con el administrador');
              } else if (textStatus === 'timeout') {
                  alert('Se ha excedido el tiempo de respuesta, debes comunicarte con el administrador');
              } else if (textStatus === 'abort') {
                  alert('La peticion fue abortada, debes comunicarte con el administrador');
              } else {
                  alert('Error desconocido, debes comunicarte con el administrador');
              }
          });

          function deDataAUnArreglo(data) {
              var arreglo = [];
              $.each (data, function (key, value) {
                  arreglo.push(parseInt(value));
              });
              return arreglo;
          }
    
    $('#button3').click(function () {
    var chart = $('#grafico').highcharts();
    chart.downloadXLS();
       
});
    
    
 
       $('#button4').click(function () {
       var chart = $('#grafico').highcharts();

chart.exportChart({
    type: 'application/pdf',
    filename: 'grafico'
});
});
    
          $('#button5').click(function () {
       var chart = $('#grafico').highcharts();
chart.exportChart({
    type: 'image/png',
    filename: 'grafico'
});
});
    
          $('#button6').click(function () {
       var chart = $('#grafico').highcharts();
chart.exportChart({
    type: 'image/jpeg',
    filename: 'grafico'
});
});

        }



        </script>



    </body>
</html>
```

```js
 <script>

function printDiv(nombreDiv) {
     var contenido= document.getElementById(nombreDiv).innerHTML;
     var contenidoOriginal= document.body.innerHTML;

     document.body.innerHTML = contenido;

     window.print();

     document.body.innerHTML = contenidoOriginal;
}

</script>
```

datos.php

```js
<?php

 require("../conexion.php");
     mysqli_query($mysqli,"SET NAMES 'utf8'");

 $nombre = strtoupper($_POST['autocomplete']);
 $codigo = strtoupper($_POST['cod_curso']) ;
 $seccion = strtoupper($_POST['seccion']);
 $anio = strtoupper($_POST['anio']);
 $semestre = strtoupper($_POST['semestre']);

    $sql2 = "SELECT nombre FROM cursos WHERE cod_curso='$codigo'";
 $result2 = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql2);

 while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)){
  $nombre_curso = $row['nombre'];
 }

 $sql = "UPDATE datos SET nombre='$nombre_curso', codigo='$codigo', seccion='$seccion', anio='$anio', semestre = '$semestre' WHERE id = '1'";
 $result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql);

 $sql3 = "SELECT nombre,seccion,semestre,anio FROM datos";
 $result3 = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql3);

 while ($registros = mysqli_fetch_array($result3))
 {


  echo "".$registros['nombre']." SECCIÓN ".$registros['seccion']." SEMESTRE ".$registros['semestre']." AÑO ".$registros['anio'];
 }

?>
```

```
   $('#button4').click(function () {
   var chart = $('#grafico').highcharts();

   chart.exportChart({
   type: 'application/pdf',
   filename: 'grafico'
    });
    });
```

Como puedo llamar al id Titulo dentro chart.exportChart?.
De ante mano gracias

Answer (score 1):

Para que tenga título el gráfico en si debe tener título y para modificar el titulo del gráfico existe una función para eso:

`chart.setTitle(objetoTitulo, objetoSubtitulo, redraw)`

por ejemplo con jQuery:

```
var chart = $('#grafico').highcharts();
chart.setTitle({text: 'Titulo Nuevo'});
```

el objeto titulo es como sigue

```
title:{
    align:center,
    floating:false,
    margin:15,
    style:{ "color": "#333333", "fontSize": "18px" },
    text: "Chart title",
    useHTML:false,
    verticalAlign:undefined,
    widthAdjust:-44,
    x:0,
    y:undefined
}
```

puedes cambiar las propiedades que tu quieras, en el ejemplo solo cambié la propiedad `text` del titulo. Te dejo un link de ejemplo

[Cambio titulo highchart](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/members/chart-settitle/)